# Camera project texture from more than one camera on to object

Tags: uv, camera

I'm projecting some Photoshop artwork on to a simple model of a mountain using camera projection. I positioned a camera in front of the mountain object and then pressed U and selected Project From View. I can rotate around my object a little bit, but the illusion breaks quite quickly. Can I project some more artwork from a slightly different angle, to give me a bit more texture for rotating around the object?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain further how you are doing the camera projection. You can use multiple projectors. Investigate the UV project modifier. It might be what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I have looked at the UV Project Modifier. I can see it has fields to add additional projectors, but I can't work out how to get each projector to project a different texture.